# Separating Hyperplanes equation for SVM

Tags: svm

I am currently reading on Separating Hyperplanes in order to understand Support Vector Machines better.

Assuming one has points of two classes in two dimensions, the resulting 
hyperplane equation would be

$$\{x :  f(x) = β_0 +  β_1x_1 + β_2x_2 = 0\}$$

which looks a lot like the classical regression equation.

However, where does the zero come from in this case?

Comment: The resulting hyperplane is the set of these points. However, how to predict this x is given by the formula
$$p(x) = \begin{cases} \text{true} & \text{if $\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 > 0$} \\ \text{false} & \text{if $\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 < 0$} \end{cases}$$ (or the other way around, this depends on the sign that you decided to use in training) and what happens when this expression is exactly 0 (i.e. x lies precisely on the boundary) is up to you...